# Angular 2 observable error - 'Parameter 'observer' implicitly has an 'any' type.'

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular 2 and am having trouble with a service that is going to return an observable.

I am seeing this error but am not sure why? I'm trying to follow some tutorials I found on the web...

**[ts] Parameter 'observer' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

My editor highlights the 'observer' work at the start of the lambda.

I am using Angular "2.0.0-rc.2"

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class LocationService {

    constructor() { }

    getLocation(): Observable<string> {

        let data: Observable<string>;

        data = new Observable<string>(observer  => {
            observer.next("123")
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is not an error, but merely info or warning.

Comment: You are quite right. The app works ok with this warning. Thanks for your help. I feel a little silly now.

Comment: There is an option in typescript to make this an error.  It is worthwhile because you can return implicit any on an interface and you suddenly do not have type safety.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not an error, but you can fix it like so:

```js
data = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>)  => {
    observer.next("123")
});
```

Don't forget to import `Observer`, though!

```js
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
```

Answer (score -3):

try this code

```
myObservable = Observable.create(((observer: Observer<string>) => {..}
```

don't forget to import Observer and Observable from 'rxjx':

```
import{Observable,Observer} from 'rxjs'
```

Comment: Isn't that almost the same answer as the one from 2016?